# How to disable keyboard for browser?

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, browser-addons, windows-11

On Windows 10 and above, Is there any way to disable my keyboard for my browser(Chrome) for some time? Only the mouse shall work.

Like we can mute one application or a browser tab, is there any way to make the keyboard non-functional for a while only for the browser.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667362/disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-kiosk-mode-for-the-chromium-browser/66278061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The script below will disable all keys for Chrome,
and will terminate when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the text below in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to start. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit.
For easy activation, you may place a shortcut to the script on the
desktop and assign it a shortcut key.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2      ; A window's title can contain string anywhere
#IfWinActive Chrome
a::
b::
c::
d::
e::
f::
g::
h::
i::
j::
k::
l::               
m::
n::
o::
p::
q::
r::
s::
t::
u::
v::
w::
x::
y::
z::
1::
2::
3::
4::
5::
6::
7::
8::
9::
0::
Space::
CapsLock::
Tab::
Enter::
Backspace::
ScrollLock::
Delete::
Insert::
Home::
End::
PgUp::
PgDn::
Up::
Down::
Left::
Right::
Numpad0::
Numpad1::
Numpad2::
Numpad3::
Numpad4::
Numpad5::
Numpad6::
Numpad7::
Numpad8::
Numpad9::
NumLock::
NumpadIns::
NumpadEnd::
NumpadDown::
NumpadPgDn::
NumpadLeft::
NumpadClear::
NumpadRight::
NumpadHome::
NumpadUp::
NumpadPgUp::
NumpadDel::
NumpadDot::
NumpadDiv::
NumpadMult::
NumpadAdd::
NumpadSub::
NumpadEnter::
F1::
F2::
F3::
F4::
F5::
F6::
F7::
F8::
F9::
F10::
F11::
F12::
F13::
F14::
F15::
F16::
F17::
F18::
F19::
F20::
F21::
F22::
F23::
F24::
LWin::
RWin::
Control::
Alt::
Shift::
LControl::
RControl::
LShift::
RShift::
LAlt::
RAlt::
Browser_Back::
Browser_Forward::
Browser_Refresh::
Browser_Stop::
Browser_Search::
Browser_Favorites::
Browser_Home::
Volume_Mute::
Volume_Down::
Volume_Up::
Media_Next::
Media_Prev::
Media_Stop::
Media_Play_Pause::
Launch_Mail::
Launch_Media::
Launch_App1::
Launch_App2::
AppsKey::
PrintScreen::
CtrlBreak::
Pause::
Break::
Help::
Sleep::
,::
.::
-::
;::
:::
_::
<::
>::
'::
\::
+::
|::
*::
`::
?::
=::
!::
"::
#::
%::
&::
/::
(::
)::
@::
£::
$::
€::
{::
[::
]::
}::
~::
return

Esc::
MsgBox Chrome keys are now enabled
ExitApp
```

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)